# Copying elements from an array to another one and counting the number of a character in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C, so I apologize for asking silly questions.

I need to copy certain elements from an array to another one, but I can't make it work and get random numbers instead. In this case I need all the elements after the smallest one from the first array to be copied to the second one.

The other thing I can't figure out is a function that counts how many times a certain symbol is used. I need to find the number of times I've used the biggest odd digit in an array.

Here's the code, I've made so far. I hope you understand most of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 100

int enter (int x[]);
int min (int x[], int y[], int n);
int sort (int x[], int n);
void print (int x[], int n);

//=============================================
int main () {
    int a[DIM], b[DIM], n, i;
    n = enter (a);
    printf("The smallest element in the first array: %d.\n The smallest element in the second array: %d.\n", min (a, b, n));

    printf("%d\n", sort (b, n));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%d ", b[i]);
        printf ("\n");

     system("pause");
     return 0;
}

//===========================================================
int enter (int x[]) { 
    int i, n;

    do {
        printf ("Enter number of elements in array: ");
        scanf ("%d", &n);
    }

    while (n < 1 || n > DIM);

    printf ("Enter %d elements:\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf ("%d", &x[i]);

    return x[i], n;
}

int min (int x[], int y[], int n) {
    int minimum, i, j=0, p;
    minimum = x[0];

    for ( i = 1 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        if ( x[i] < minimum ) {
            minimum = x[i];
            p = i+1;
        }
    } 

    for (i = p+1; i<n; i++ && j++) {
        x[i] = y[j];
    }

    return minimum;
}

int sort (int x[], int n) {
    int i, j, a; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
             if (x[i] > x[j]){
                 a = x[i];
                 x[i] = x[j];
                 x[j] = a;
             }
         }
    }
    printf("Elements from array in ascending order: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", x[i]);

    return x[i];
}
```

Comment: Please, please indent your code correctly. It will be so difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: The brace noise doesn't help much either. That code could easily be 20 lines.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find the number of times I've used the biggest odd digit in
>   an array.

Fist sort your array start at the end and find the biggest odd number. You can find a odd number by `number%2==1`. Finally count equal numbers:

```
// sort the array
sort(b, n); // sort function from your questions code

// find the biggest odd number
int i = n-1;
while ( i >= 0 && b[i]%2 == 0 )
{
    i --;
}

// count the biggest odd number
count = 0;
int j = i;
while ( j >= 0 && b[i]==b[j] ) // note first time i==j ! 
{
    count ++;
    j --;
}
```

If you don't want to sort your array use this:

```
// find the biggest odd number
int oddInx = -1;
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( b[i]%2 == 1 && ( oddInx < 0 || b[i] > b[oddInx] ) )
        oddInx = i;
}

// count the biggest odd number
count = 0;
if ( oddInx >= 0 )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( b[i] == b[oddInx] )
            count ++;
    }
}
```